# Running Java tests in Visual Studio Code without Maven?

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code, classpath

I try to run some tests for my Java project in Visual Studio Code. I get the error:

```
Error occurred: Exception in thread "main" Error occurred: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore
```

It's clear that JUnit is not part of my classpath. All my googling points into the direction that I should solve this with Maven dependencies. However my bigest problem is, that this is a quite old legacy project that uses Ant, not Maven. Therefore the question is: is there a way to add JUnit to the classpath without Maven  (e.g. somewhere in the user config) so Visual Studio Code's Java testrunner can find it and run the tests?